# Format for Historical Fiction Book

Tags: formatting

I am close to finishing my historical fiction book, and I need to know the following:

Should you indent at the beginning of every paragraph?

If you do indent, what size should the indent be?

Size of Line spacing?

After a quote should you have a capital letter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is a tab button on a regular computer or laptop for an indent if that’s what you are using, if there isn’t a tab button, use five spaces. If you are handwriting your work, use the width of three fingers.

After a quote (if it’s dialogue) you should have a capital letter, because it’s the start of a sentence.

Example:

```
 “No!”
 “Why not?”
 “Because I don’t feel like it!”
 “Why not?”
 “Dylan, for crying out loud would you just leave it alone!”
```

See how you indent and put a capital on dialogue.